# Adding line break if $_Post is populated

Tags: php, html, string

Trying to build a Supply Request form that will send me an HTML formatted email upon submission. It will contain 100+ supplies, but I need to include Text before some of the fields (e.g. Qty:) that are posting and then a `<br>` after to have the next field start on a new line.

The issue I'm having is that regardless of whatever I do, the un-selected supplies cause gaps in the email where that product should have been.

The email should display something like this:

```
Hi Name, we received your request! Below is a list of everything you requested.

Vendor: Product 1

Qty: 5

Notes:


Vendor: Product 3

Qty: 5

Notes:
```

Code is below.

```
<?php
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Company <no-reply@company.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: myemail@company.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: " . $_POST["EmailWork"] . "\r\n";
$subject = "Supply Request";
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$EmailWork = $_POST["EmailWork"];
$Product1 = $_POST["Product1"];
$Product2 = $_POST["Product2"];
$Product3 = $_POST["Product3"];
$Notes1 = $_POST["Notes1"];
$Notes2 = $_POST["Notes2"];
$Notes3 = $_POST["Notes3"];
$Qty1 = $_POST["Qty1"];
$Qty2 = $_POST["Qty2"];
$Qty3 = $_POST["Qty3"];
$to = 'myemail@company.com';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Staff Portal Submission: Add a Bookmark</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F7F7F7" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" offset="0" topmargin="0">
    <table bgcolor="#F7F7F7" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="660">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="50" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top"><img height="190" src="#" width="660"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" width="660">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="color: rgba(44, 68, 85, 0.8); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">'. "Hi" . $_POST['Name'] . ", we received your request! Below is a list of everything you requested." . '</span></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>'. $_POST['Product1'] . $_POST['Qty1'] . $_POST['Notes1'] . $_POST['Product2'] . $_POST['Qty2'] . $_POST['Notes2'] . $_POST['Product3'] . $_POST['Qty3'] . $_POST['Notes3'] .'</td>
                              </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
';

if ($Name && $EmailWork)
{
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/assets/ssi/received.asp\">";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/assets/ssi/error.asp\">";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/assets/ssi/incomplete.asp\">";
}

?>
```

Form Example

```
<form action="/assets/ssi/hub/add/submit7.inc.php" method="post">
<input class="form-check-input" id="Product1" name="Product" type="checkbox" value="<br>Exam Glove McKesson 3.5C Small Gloves <br>Qty: "></div>
<input class="form-control" id="Qty[]" name="Qty[]" type="text">
<input class="form-control" id="Notes[1]" name="Notes[1]" type="text">
<button class="btn btn-secondary float-end text-uppercase" type="submit">Submit Order</button>
</form>
```

This is a screenshot of what the page would somewhat look like... Obviously it would have A LOT more on it:

[image]

Comment: Please reduce the text in the post. It looks like a whole story. Please see [ask] and [tour] about creating a [mre]; with the focus op minimal!

Comment: Why don't you create an array of key value pairs using the post data and then loop a <tr> in the table to show all the values?

Comment: So do you start at `$_POST['Product1']` and go all the way up to `$_POST['Product100']` and beyond? I assume you're not intending to hard-code all of those into the `$message = ....` line? The obvious solution is to use a loop. In each loop iteration, check the content with the `empty()` function before adding any content or line breaks to the $message string. Might be easier if your form just submits everything under `$_POST["Product"]` (without the numbers, and the same pattern for all the other fields) using array syntax i.e. `name="Product[]`.

Comment: What's missing from your question now is a clear description of how it will be obvious that a supply is "unselected". Will there simply be no $_POST data at all for that product? Or is there a specific $_POST field which indicates whether it's been selected or not? In your [earlier version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71177384/revisions) you mentioned a checkbox? What is its name? Can we see the full HTML for one supply entry in the form, please?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I assume in reality the form actually contains lots of those inputs, repeating? Otherwise you'd never be able to submit more than one at once.

Comment: I'm trying to make a page where someone can search for EVERYTHING in our supply room, and when they find what they need, check the box, put how many of that item they want, add any notes, and repeat for another item if necessary and then I get an email saying Jane is requesting 2 of this item and 3 of that item... I only want to know what items I need to grab and take to Jane. I rigged the checkbox to show the name of the item. I updated the post to include a sample of the Form.

Answer (score 1):

You haven's shown your form.

Remember that within form you can use a value as an array:

```html
<input type="text" name="products[]" />
```

if you have multiple inputs with the name ending with `[]`, all the inputs are read and posted as an array `$_POST["products"]`. You can then loop through the post to see all the values from input called "products[]".

Comment: I just tried that, updated my 2 inputs for Notes and Qty, e.g <input class="form-control" id="Qty[]" name="Qty[]" type="text"></div> (removed the number and added [], and then added a $Qty = $_POST['Qty'] on the other page that submits, but the email shows Array in place of where the text should be?

Comment: `the email shows Array in place of where the text should be`...yes because as the answer says you need to _loop through_ that array.

Comment: Yeah, so I had found this question last night and tried it out this morning thinking it was very similar to what I needed, but for some reason could not get it to work for me. This Youtube video I'm watching trying to explain loops just isn't helping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076541/ignore-empty-form-fields-when-sending-php/26076974

Comment: ```php
foreach ($_POST["products"] as $product) {
echo $product; // returns string - value of one of the input
}
```
The application should be brainstormed before a development starts. 
You can have another input, which name would be name of the product for example of mine, and the value would be a count of products a user wants to buy. Then, when you loop through the products, you can get a count from another value from POST (out of products[])

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly trickier to get right than it looks, partly due to the way checkboxes are treated when submitting a HTML form - if the checkbox isn't checked, it simply isn't submitted. This means if you're submitting lists of repeating fields which are meant to be matched with each checkbox, they'll get out of sync because - for example - if you have 4 rows of fields, and check 2 boxes, you'll get 4 lots of the other fields, but only 2 checkboxes, making it hard/impossible to work out which checkbox goes with which fields in the POST data.

This can be resolved by tweaking your form a bit. It needed a few fixes anyway from your version above.

Changes as follows:

- most importantly, using array syntax for the Products field, and **numbering the indices** - this means that the numbering will be preserved when submitting, even if not all the boxes are ticked. This means you can match the index of the checkbox with the indices of the accompanying fields in the various arrays in `$_POST`.
- don't use IDs on repeating fields. This is invalid in HTML, because IDs are, by definition, meant to be unique.
- don't number the Notes fields.
- I strongly recommend not including formatting information or the text of your emails in the `value` of the products field...keep the formatting aspect all in one place, when you're constructing your message in the PHP code.

Example of new form structure:

```
<form action="/assets/ssi/hub/add/submit7.inc.php" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" />
  Email: <input type="email" name="EmailWork" /><br/>
  ...
   <input class="form-check-input" name="Product[0]" type="checkbox" value="Exam Glove McKesson 3.5C Small Gloves"></div>
  <input class="form-control" name="Qty[]" type="text">
  <input class="form-control" name="Notes[]" type="text">
  <br/>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="Product[1]" type="checkbox" value="Product no. 1"></div>
  <input class="form-control" name="Qty[]" type="text">
  <input class="form-control" name="Notes[]" type="text">
  <br/>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="Product[2]" type="checkbox" value="Product no. 2"></div>
  <input class="form-control" name="Qty[]" type="text">
  <input class="form-control" name="Notes[]" type="text">
  <br/>
  <input class="form-check-input" name="Product[3]" type="checkbox" value="Product no. 3"></div>
  <input class="form-control" name="Qty[]" type="text">
  <input class="form-control" name="Notes[]" type="text">
  <br/>
  ...
  <button class="btn btn-secondary float-end text-uppercase" type="submit" name="submit">Submit Order</button>
</form>
```

And then the PHP code can use a simple `foreach` loop to go through all the selected Product checkboxes (since those will be the only checkbox values sent in the POST data), get the index (key) and value of each, and output that value plus the entries from the other POST arrays which match the key. Each iteration of the loop will create a new row in the table.

PHP code:

```
$Name = $_POST["Name"];
$EmailWork = $_POST["EmailWork"];

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Company <no-reply@company.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: myemail@company.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: " . $EmailWork . "\r\n";
$subject = "Supply Request";
$to = 'myemail@company.com';
$message = '
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Staff Portal Submission: Add a Bookmark</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F7F7F7" leftmargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" offset="0" topmargin="0">
    <table bgcolor="#F7F7F7" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="660">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="50" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top"><img height="190" src="#" width="660"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" valign="top">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="20" width="660">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><span style="color: rgba(44, 68, 85, 0.8); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18px;">'. "Hi " . $Name . ", we received your request! Below is a list of everything you requested." . '</span></td>
                                </tr>';
                                
foreach ($_POST["Product"] as $key => $val)
{
    $message .= "<tr><td>Vendor: ".$val."<br/>Qty: ".$_POST['Qty'][$key]."<br/>Notes: ".$_POST['Notes'][$key]."</td></tr>";
}
                                
                                
$message .=                            '</table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
';

if ($Name && $EmailWork)
{
    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/assets/ssi/received.asp\">";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/assets/ssi/error.asp\">";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=/assets/ssi/incomplete.asp\">";
}
```