# How to submit fetched value into multiple rows

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

I am trying to fetch each order from database with a checkbox so that the customer can select/confirm the paypal payment for their orders, but when the form is submitted it only updates 1 row with the paytype & confirmation but I need it to update the rows of the orders that have been checked with checkbox

How do I update the paytype & confirmation columns for the selected/checked orders only?

Thanks

Here is my paypal_confirmation.html page where customer can select which orders to confirm...

```
<form method="POST" action="../PHP/services.php">

<?php
 $userdetails = $_SESSION['usr_name'];
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `username` = '$userdetails'");
 $stmt->execute();
 $fetchy = $stmt->fetchAll();

 foreach ($fetchy as $fetch) {
?>

<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $userdetails ?>" name="username">
<input type="hidden" value="PayPal" name="paytype">
<input type="hidden" value="Confirmed" name="confirmation">

<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $fetch['uid']; ?>" name="uid">

<img src="/images/temp/<?php echo $fetch['prodimage']; ?>">

<?php
}
?>

<button type="submit" name="PayPalConfirm">Submit</button>

</form>
```

And here is my services.php that handles the database table update...

```
 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['PayPalConfirm'])) {

    $userdetails = $_SESSION['usr_name'];
    $paytype = $_POST['paytype'];
    $confirmation = $_POST['confirmation'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];

    $stmt = "UPDATE orders SET paytype = :paytype, confirmation = :confirmation WHERE uid = :uid";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($stmt);
    $stmt->bindParam(':paytype', $_POST['paytype'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':confirmation', $_POST['confirmation'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $_POST['uid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();

    ?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.my-site.co.uk/Checkout/paypal_complete.php" />
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: in general to submit multiple items for fields with the same name you need to use array syntax in your HTML form element e.g. `name="username[]"`, `name="uid[]"` etc. That'll enable submission of multiple sets of data. Then in the PHP, obviously you'll need a `for` loop to go through the items.

Comment: In terms of only processing the selected ones, well, in HTML forms a value is only submitted for a checkbox if it was checked. Un-checked boxes just aren't submitted. So that allows you to see which ones were ticked when the form is submitted.

Comment: Well yeah I understand it processes the checked ones, thats what I'm trying to do, what do you mean by `name="uid[]"` would this be numbered? how would I do this so its a different name foreach order?

Comment: You don't need a different name for each order, just a different index. If you have multiple `name="uid"` fields, then when the form is submitted, `$_POST["uid"]` will be a numbered array of all the values from all the fields with that name.

Comment: I actually wrote an answer a few weeks ago which covers almost the same kind of scenario (from a technical point of view, the data involved was different but the principle was the same - trying to get only the rows from a form where the checkbox on that row was checked). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71214107/5947043

Comment: @ADyson so I have my names set like `name="uid[]"` and inside my PHP I have `$uid = $_POST[uid][0]` &  `$uid = $_POST[uid][1]` but again its just updating one row, do I also need to change the `$uid` and do I also need to add the `[0]` & `[1]` into the WHERE statement too? sorry for the questions I have only ever done forms with single field entries

Comment: `again its just updating one row`...well if you're selecting $_POST[uid][0] specifically then that's only one specific item from the array. Like I said above, you need to _loop_ through the array to get all the entries, and run the `UPDATE` statement repeatedly, once for each entry (you can prepare it once, but then bind and execute it multiple times). Again, see the answer link I posted above, it shows how your form needs to be structured and how to loop through the $_POST data to get the selected items. (I suggest echoing them first as a test to check the data, and then rebuild your SQL.)